# Java Handling NPE in Spring Data native query Projections

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, nativequery

I am wondering if there is a way to check if the result object of a native query contains of all nulls. E.g. the following code tries to get a projection using nativeQuery but since all the fields are null, it throws NPE.

Projection:

```
public interface MetricsCountData {
    Long getLikes ();

    Long getComments ();

    Long getImpressions ();

    Long getShares ();
}
```

Repository Method:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select sum(impressions) as impressions, sum(likes) as likes, sum(comments) as comments, sum(shares) as shares " +
            "from facebook_post_analytics As a " +
            "JOIN " +
            "(select post_id, max(id) As id " +
            "from facebook_post_analytics " +
            "where partner_id = :partnerId " +
            "AND page_id = :pageId " +
            "AND insights_epoch BETWEEN :startEpoch AND :endEpoch " +
            "group by post_id) AS b " +
            "ON a.id = b.id")
    MetricsCountData findFacebookMetricsData(Long partnerId, String pageId, Long startEpoch, Long endEpoch);
```

Snippet in my service class:

```
MetricsCountData metricsCountData = dataRepository.findFacebookMetricsData(partnerId,pageId,startEpoch,endEpoch);

if(metricsCountData == null)                        //Useless Check
{
    return;
}else{
    return metricsCountData.getImpressions() + metricsCountData.getLikes();       //Representative Logic
}
```

Now, is there a way to easily check whether all projection getters are null because the metricsCountObject is always non-null and I am invariably going inside else flow and getting NPE there.

Note: I have many getters in my projection so doing a prior null check for each one of them is being avoided. Also, I have tried using Object[], it too has the same problem.

Is there a better way?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting NPE inside the else block if `metricsCountData != null`?. You may want to inform the controller when a MetricsCountData was not found and throw a custom exception rather than returning.

Comment: metricsCountObject is always non-null and I am invariably going inside else flow and getting NPE there.

Comment: How can you return nothing or a number from the same method? Does that compile?

Answer (score 0):

You can either check in on the java side:

```
if(metricsCountData == null || metricsCountData.getImpressions() == null || metricsCountData.getLikes() == null)                        //Useless Check
{
    return;
}else{
    return metricsCountData.getImpressions() + metricsCountData.getLikes();       //Representative Logic
}
```

Or on the SQL side by adding a HAVING-clause to your query:

```
HAVING sum(impressions) IS NOT NULL AND sum(likes) IS NOT NULL
```

The code snippets only take impressions and likes into account, but you obviously can extend that to other properties as well.